# Getting the gold price from the web - python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, web

I am trying to get the gold price and it's percentage increase / decrease (using web scraping). I am new to web scraping. The main issue is that the scraped html is dissimilar to the websites html (on google)

Hello

I am trying to make a python program to scrape the gold price off this website - https://goldprice.org/. I am completely new to the world of web-scraping, but have managed to come up with the following lines of python:

```
# this should print the website's html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://goldprice.org/"

req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

data = req.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

this works and outputs html after running.

The next step is to parse the data and find the following pieces of information:

[data to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF6MK.png)
(the gold price and the percentage increase / decrease)

I have no idea how to do this, but I tried to implement a searching algorithm like so:

```
def SearchSoup(toFind):
    """Finds all the indexes of toFind in the soup"""
    mentionIdx = []
    current = ""
    strLen = len(toFind)

    start = 0
    for i in range(len(soup)):
        if i - start == strLen:
            start = i

        if soup[i] != toFind[i - start]:
            start = i + 1
            current = ""
            continue
        
        current += soup[i]
        if toFind == current:
            mentionIdx.append(start)
    
    return mentionIdx
```

this does give me a traceback error when parsing the soup:

```
KeyError: 0" - stems from the "if soup[i] != toFind[i - start]:" and line 1573, in __getitem__ return self.attrs[key]
                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
```

The main problem is that in the scraped html code, the gold price / gold %inc/dec does not seem to be included. I manually read through every line in it, but it wasn't there. Furthermore, when I went onto the actual website and checked the html on it (by pressing fn + f12), the scraped html differed from it.

I am quite lost here :)

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked questions here.  That web site is created dynamically, through Javascript.  If you do View Source in your browser, you'll see what `requests` sees, which does not include any prices.  What you see in the F12 display is the dynamic object model created by Javascript.  To get that, you need to use a real browser, using `Selenium` or `requests-html`, or see if they have a public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data of gold price/change use their Ajax API:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
}

data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()

# print(data)

print(data["items"][0]["xauPrice"], data["items"][0]["pcXau"])
```

Prints:

```
2024.405 -4.4504
```

---

The full response looks like this (this includes gold and silver):

```py
{
    "ts": 1701714890300,
    "tsj": 1701714885583,
    "date": "Dec 4th 2023, 01:34:45 pm NY",
    "items": [
        {
            "curr": "USD",
            "xauPrice": 2024.0325,
            "xagPrice": 24.514,
            "chgXau": -94.6625,
            "chgXag": -1.2275,
            "pcXau": -4.468,
            "pcXag": -4.7686,
            "xauClose": 2118.695,
            "xagClose": 25.7415,
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: How did you find the URL "https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD"?

Comment: @Nathan I opened web developer tools -> Network tab in browser and refreshed the page. You should see the URL there.